# How to replace 2 double quotes into single double quotes in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have text file inside there one column having 2 double quotes. I am trying to replacing them but not able to get the result.

Example:

In text file the data is:

```
From Date,To Date,Item Number,Item Description
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"                        
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"                        
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"                        
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"
```

But while reading this file as dataframe it is showing:

```
From Date   To Date     Item Number    Item Description
01/31/2022  02/06/2022   100455       "REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"      10ML"                        
01/31/2022  02/06/2022   100455       "REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"      10ML"                        
01/31/2022  02/06/2022   100455       "REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"      10ML"                        
01/31/2022  02/06/2022   100455       "REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"      10ML"
```

I am running below code-

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\iMedical\Anamoly Script\dhs\KF_Standard_Customer_Activity_Data_February072022.txt", delimiter =',')
print(df.head())
print(df['Item Description'])
df1 = df.replace({r'"' : ''}, regex = True)
print(df1['Item Description'])
df1.to_csv(r"D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\iMedical\Anamoly Script\dhs\out.txt", index=False, sep=',')
```

In Output File I am getting below record-

```
From Date,To Date,Item Number,Item Description
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"                        
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"                        
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"                        
01/31/2022,02/06/2022,100455,"REMICADE INJ 100MG    ""R""       10ML"
```

Comment: Can you post `df['Item Description'].head().tolist()` ?

Comment: ['REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"       10ML', 'REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"       10ML', 'REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"       10ML', 'REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"       10ML', 'REMICADE INJ 100MG    "R"       10ML']

Comment: Not understand, there are one `"` like need in `df['Item Description']`, so why need replace?

Comment: In file it is showing 2 but while reading as dataframe it is showing 1.

Comment: And what need? Title is `How to replace 2 double quotes into single double quotes in dataframe?` so why need repalce them if correct read from file?

Answer (score 0):

This is an effect of the CSV encoding. CSV does not really have a universally accepted spec, but [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) is an attempt, which states (in section 2.7):

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.

So, for example, the text

```
"Hello", she said.
```

gets written into the file as

```
"""Hello"", she said."
```

Pandas' `read_csv` and `to_csv` functions take care of this for you, as does the `csv` module of the standard library.

Comment: Can you please provide me sample code for this?